# why is php timezone is correct on local host, but incorrect after uploading to server?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone, phpmyadmin

I am using php, and mysql. When i insert a time value into mysql database on my local host, the correct time is applied. i am using the `now()` function for the time.

When i insert the time values into my_sql database on my web-hosting account, it shows the wrong time zone.

if a user from a different time zone posts something, and i am viewing it in my time zone, how can i set it so the time displayed to the user is relative to where the user is viewing it from.

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO notifications (stamp) 
            VALUES (now());
```

Comment: Look into your php.ini, there you can set the timezone of the server.

Comment: The server is on a different time zone!

Comment: a) What is the server's time zone set to?  b) What time zone is set in php.ini? c) What time zone is set in mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server's in a different time zone.

You can set the timezone in PHP and in MySQL.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

And in MySQL:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

Or, you can store your times as `timestamp` columns, which are always UTC in the underlying data.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for `NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

> The value is expressed in the current time zone.

So if your local machine is in a different time zone to your host's machine, you *will* see different results.

You might want to consider using [`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) instead. (It's not clear to me whether this will return a `DATETIME` value if used in the appropriate context, but that's probably what you want.)

Comment: if a user from a different time zone posts something, and another user is viewing it in a different time zone, how can i set it so the time displayed to the user is relative to where the user is viewing it from. will using UTC_TIMESTAMP() do this? is their anyway to do this without forcing the user to enter what timezone they are located in?

Comment: @arboles: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You should write down *concrete* examples, with specific times and time zones, then work out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your webservers php.ini probably has a different timezone set.

You can change it in your php file via [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)